# Trying to save node or reference to node in a list

Tags: python, algorithm, tree, binary, structure

I have a tree class in which the class gets initialized with a data, left, and right attributes.
in the same class I have a "save" method.
I am using a list as a queue.
I am attempting to create a "save" method which takes only one argument "data".
The purpose of this save method is to dequeue from my list, check that node to see if its empty and if it is then it saves my data there. Otherwise it enqueues the 2 children of that node into the list.
The purpose of this is to save data in level order into the tree.
Because the class gets initialized there is always at least 1 element in the tree which is the root node.

The issue i keep running into is that whenever i append the self.data (the root node, not the data im currently trying to add) into my list at the beginning of the save method it only saves the data there.
and obviously when I then try to append the left and right child of this int i get an error because the int has no left or right attributes.

I am wondering how to save the node in the list instead of the data at the node.

```
class Tree():
    aqueue = []
    def __init__(self, item):
        self.item = item
        self.leftchild = None
        self.rightchild = None
        self.aqueue.append(self.item)
        
    def add(self, newitem):
        temp = self.myqueue.pop(0)
        if temp is None:
            temp = Tree(newitem)
        else:
            self.aqueue.append(temp.leftchild)
            self.aqueue.append(temp.rightcild)
            temp.add(newitem)
        
        self.aqueue.clear() #this is meant to clear queue of all nodes after the recursions are complete
        self.aqueue.append(self.item) #this is meant to return the root node to the queue so that it is the only item for next time
```

Comment: Please include your code so that we can better help you.

Comment: "and obviously when I then try to.." Yes, obviously :-)  How about a distilled code sample so we know what the heck you're talking about (and that your code does what you think it does).

Comment: Yes I have added the code to the original post

Comment: you haven't though... you've added a link to a picture of the code. _copy_ the code into the question please (I haven't downvoted you, but read this for why images of code are bad: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/)

Comment: I see, thank you for letting me know. I have attached the code within the body now.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of obvious issues with your code: both the if and else branch return, so the code after will never run, `temp == newitem` is an equality expression, but even if it was an assignment it wouldn't do anything:

```
def add(self, newitem):
    temp = self.myqueue.pop(0)
    if temp == None:       # should use temp is None
        temp == newitem    # temp = newitem still wouldn't do anything
        return True
    else:
        self.aqueue.append(temp.leftchild)
        self.aqueue.append(temp.rightcild)
        return temp.add(newitem)
    
    # you will never get here, since both branches of the if returns
    self.aqueue.clear()            # delete everything in the list..?
    self.aqueue.append(self.item)
```

Comment: I see, I have made a few changes reflecting in the original post. Within the if statement if the current node is empty then I need to create a new node within the tree which I have done now. That was an poor error on my part. While running debugger I still see that  items are being added to aqueue as just ints. So they fail when I attempt to append their left/right nodes within the else statement. What may be causing this

Comment: In your updated code, you're dropping temp on the floor in the true branch of the if-statement. If I were you, I'd start with pen and paper, draw an empty Tree, and then draw the operations needed to add the first element - you need to get a conceptual understanding before coding the problem. As a step in debugging the issue, you should write a function that prints the entire tree, so that you can verify that your code matches the work you did with pen-and-paper...